# Extend CRM Dynamics Site Map

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

How can one update the site map in Dynamics CRM in a way that it extends the existing site map rather than overriding the existing site map?

I have googled this but could not find anything. Maybe the search terminology is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to Edit the Site map is Using "Site Map Editor" from [XRMToolBox](http://www.xrmtoolbox.com/)

Comment: For those on Dynamics CRM 365, there is now an in-built Site Map editor within CRM